# Converting visually formatted plain text output to array

Tags: php, arrays, text, explode

I am using Virtualmin and testing out the Remote API PHP features for a project. I can't seem to find any good documentation on this so I am testing out different functions randomly.

Making an API call is done like this:

```
<?php
$result = shell_exec("wget -O - --quiet --http-user=root --http-passwd=pass --no-check-certificate 'https://localhost:10000/virtual-server/remote.cgi?program=list-users&domain=testdomain.co.uk'");

echo $result;
?>
```

The issue I am facing is the result output is plain text formatted in a way which is easily readable. I have provided an example image below. I have tried using explode to create an array which is easily manageable but I cannot explode by blank space as parts such as "real name" or the actual real names have spaces? This also seems to output tens of empty array parts `[1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] =>`

[image]

This is what I currently have which is providing numerous empty array values.

```
$lines = explode("\n", $result);
$out = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $parts = explode(" ", $line);
}
```

Ideally I would like the array to work like a multidimensional array.

Comment: That format looks like a reporting format. Ie. not meant to be parsed as a CSV or fixed-length file. Are there any online examples or documentation about getting the data in a different format?

Comment: Is there a reason you're shelling out to `wget` instead of using `file_get_contents` or `fopen`?

Comment: @waterloomatt I cannot find any proper documentation about this so I am kind of left experimenting and creating my own methods to implement it.

Comment: See this - https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/developer/http/, specifically the section titled `JSON and XML Output`. Quote, `If you would prefer JSON format output, add the json=1 parameter to the remote API call...`

Comment: @JacobMulquin This is what the very limited documentation supplied instructed, as I am new to working with servers I am trying to figure it out as I go. I did download an API library but couldn't seem to get it working.

Comment: @waterloomatt I will give that a go, do you happen to have any idea what I would add to  'multiline=' as it says I would need to use that to convert to JSON. No idea what multiline is referring to.

Comment: @Snappysites A few paragraphs up in the documentation has an example with an empty `multiline=`, try out the URL in your browser and see if it outputs correctly.